# Why do we need dispatcher in Flux?

Tags: reactjs, aurelia, flux

This is not a React specific question. I'm thinking of implementing Flux in Aurelia/Angularjs.

While reading up on flux, I'm not convinced of the need of the dispatcher step. Why can't a component call the store directly to update and retrieve data? Is there anything wrong with that approach?

For example: If I have a `CarStore` that can create new cars, update cars and get a list of cars(just a thin layer on the CRUD api), I should be able to retrieve/update the list by directly calling the store from the `car-grid` component. Since the store is a singleton, whenever the list updates, `car-grid` should automatically get the new items. What is the benefit of using a dispatcher in this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

I've created several large apps using React-native with Redux as the store / view state updater.

The dispatch action is synchronous regardless. There's a big disadvantage to using dispatchers, you lose the function signature. (Debugging, auto-catching type-errors, refactoring lost, multiple declarations of the same function, list goes on)

Never had to use a dispatcher and its caused no issues. Within the actions we simply call getState().dispatch. The store is a singleton anyhow, it's heavily recommended you don't have multiple stores. (Why would you do that...)

Answer (score 1):

You can see [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/07/30/flux-actions-and-the-dispatcher.html#why-we-need-a-dispatcher) why are dispatchers important (check out the section  Why We Need a Dispatcher). The way I see it, the idea is basically being able to access to various stores in a synchronous way (one callback finishes before another one is called). You can make this thanks to the `waitFor` method, which **allows you to wait for a store to finish processing an action** (or more tan one). There is a good example [in the docs](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/dispatcher.html). For example, your application may grow and instead of having just that CarStore you have another Store whose updates depend on the CarStore updates.

Comment: Why can't that dependency be managed in the components though? For example you could use promises if you wanted to update multiple stores that are dependent on each other.

Comment: For example we need to remove a car from `WishlistStore` when it gets added to the `CartStore`. From your component, you could add a car to `CartStore` which returns a promise and when it's successful you update `WishlistStore`.

Comment: I guess you could do it that way, but Flux gives you dispatchers and functions as a tool to make it easier. At the extreme case, you could do everything with pure JavaScript, a framework simply gives you some tools and patterns to make it easier and/or better organized.

Comment: That I understand. I'm only curious behind the rationale of organizing program in such way.

Comment: The way I see it, with dispatchers you have all that kind of logic there and not every Flux user doing it at the Components however he wants. It's a common situation and solving it using always the same method usually helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you will only ever have one store, then a dispatcher is redundant in my opinion. If you have multiple stores however, then a dispatcher is important so that actions don't need to know about each of these stores.

Please note that I am not saying that you should ditch the dispatcher if you only have one store. It's still a good pattern as it gives you the option of supporting multiple stores if you ever need to in the future.